# why these code work but dont add record to my database

Tags: c#, sql, database

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=CASPER_NIRVANA\FARID;Initial Catalog=proje;Integrated Security=True";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO projetablosu(basvuru_no)VALUES(@basvuru_no)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("basvuru_no", textBox1.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? I think from your code, you are not opening the connection before executing the query. You should do a conn.Open()

Comment: Open a connection and dispose resource after usage. use as reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following and amend your questio appropriately:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: maybe missing `@`?

Answer (score 4):

Well, if it doesn't add the record to the database you can hardly say it works, can you?

You are missing the `@` in the parameter. Instead of

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("basvuru_no", textBox1.Text);
```

use

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@basvuru_no", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
```

You should also read [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Also, as Artem wrote in his comment, you should dispose your disposable objects. The proper way to do it is with the `using` statement:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CASPER_NIRVANA\FARID;Initial Catalog=proje;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO projetablosu(basvuru_no)VALUES(@basvuru_no)", conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@basvuru_no", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Also note that you can use the constructors to pass all the properties you have set manually in your code, making the code shorter and more readable.

Answer (score -2):

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CASPER_NIRVANA\FARID;Initial Catalog=proje;Integrated Security=True");
string query = "INSERT INTO projetablosu(basvuru_no)VALUES('"+textBox1.Text+"')";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

// Try This Code, This Will Definately works for u

Comment: I usually don't bother downvoting answers, but the code you posted is a security risk, since it's an open door for SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Yup if the Security is the issue then we should use this cmd.Parameters.Add("@basvuru_no", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;

Comment: Security is always an issue. even when writing in-office desktop applications.